# Open/Access Anti-Virus Websites

Tags: windows-11, virus, anti-virus

I have a problem with a virus in Windows 11. I think it's a Trojan-32. So far I've seen the following "Vir Tool:Win32/DefenderTamperingRestore" and "Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.Hml" both which have been said to be removed by Microsoft Safety Scanner and Microsoft Security Defender, respectively. Yet, the problem still persists. I've tried using anti-virus softwares on demand by downloading them through another computer on a flash drive. Softwares like Malwarebytes and Avast as they've been brought up with issues like this - yet even after running full scans on those, quarantining and deleting anything that shows, the problem still persists.

When trying to access an Anti-Virus website, the following shows up "This site can't be reached. The webpage at https://www.mcafee.com/might be temporarily down or it may have
moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID" Yes I've tried using different browsers and internet, but the same problem is present.

Please help me with a solution as I've been at this for the past couple days and I'd really hate to have to re-download Windows and recover/wipe my computer as it would cause a lot of difficulties.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=remove+virus

Comment: Unfortunately, you may have to recover from your backups. This is one of the reasons why we take backups.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I would recommend if you don't want to reset and you don't have a backup (or maybe just a very old backup that you would lose your data on)

Note: Please be connected to the internet for this
Other note: restart in between all of these steps

1. Assuming you are on windows 10 or above (if you are on windows 8 or below then skip this step) open windows defender and then change the scan type to microsoft defender offline scan, then run the scan (it will restart your computer and take a while but that will weed out most of the bad stuff).
2. Go to https://www.hitmanpro.com/en-us/downloads and download the latest version of hitmanpro (not the version that has .alert on the end).
3. Run the tool and scan your computer for malware. If it find anything (which there is a very high chance it will) click next and activate the free trial
   using your email, then remove the malware and restart.
4. Go to https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/free-virus-removal-tool and download Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool and run it, accept the terms and conditions and before you anything else, click Change parameters. Then tick every box in the menu and click ok (not cancel or the close button).
   Then click Start scan and wait for it to scan, if it finds any malware, then follow the instructions to remove it.
5. Download adwcleaner from here: https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner, run it and scan, then remove the malware.
6. Download Malwarebytes (This is made by the same company as adwcleaner) https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/thankyou and run the downloaded file. Then install it by following the on screen instructions and say that you're at home when it asks you. When it is installed and you have restarted, click the settings icon in the top right and select security in the bar at the top. Then scroll down until you see scan options and everything in the scan options on (like scan for rootkits and use expert system algorithms to identify threats). Then go back home by clicking the X in the top right. Click on the scanner tab (do not click on the blue 'scan' button), then click on advanced scanners and click on the blue 'configure scan button underneath custom scan. Tick all the boxes next to your drive letter(s) and tick the box that says 'scan for rootkits'. Then wait until it has scanned and remove all the threats by clicking the quarantine button. Then restart and you should be good to go!

If this works or doesn't work tell me by commenting.
Have a good day and a fixed and nice and clean computer!

Answer (score 0):

> yet even after running full scans on those, quarantining and deleting
> anything that shows, the problem still persists.

You have attracted viruses which have proven they cannot be readily eradicated.

The only practical solution now is to back up your data on an external drive and then reinstall Windows.

You may wish to start to use one of the full backup programs that allow you to recover from a full backup.

This is not a Windows 11 problem of any kind.

**Note:  Also run TDSS Killer to find and get rid of Root Kit Viruses.**

Comment: Note that *some* malware can survive a full OS reinstall: https://www.pcmag.com/news/malware-that-can-survive-os-reinstalls-strikes-again-likely-for-cyberespionage [This is likely only on high-value machines, e.g., targeting state security.]

Comment: Root Kit viruses can do that.